# How to get response from firebase function to firebase static index.html

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am try to getting my firebase database response in firebase static file of index.html. 
  In firebase index.js, am getting database and returning the all ref by getUsers method then get response from getusers by promise (then)method from there am sending my res.send(res) to index.html of firebase static files. but am not getting any response in data parameteer in getajax call but getting the scucess status in status parameter.

```
     firebase folder structure
      functions
             |_ index.js
      public
            |_index.html
```

````
Index.html -- firebase public index.hmlt 

           <script>

            const _url_prod = "https://nodejs-fef5b.firebaseapp.com/get";

             $('button').click(function(){
               $.get(_url_prod,(data,status)=>{
                       console.log("data",data);
                       console.log("status",status)
              })
            </script>


index.js-- firebase function folder has index.js


var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://nodejs-crud-12758.firebaseio.com"
});
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const  app = express();

async function getUsers(){
    const ref = await firebaseApp.database().ref('users');
    return  ref.once('value').then(data => {
          data.val();
        })
}
app.get('/get',(req,res)=>{
   getUsers().then(items => {
       res.send(items);
    });
})
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index.html :

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
$.get('http://192.168.56.1:5555/get', (data, success) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(success);
})
</script>
```

your script :

```
async function getUsers() {
    return await 
        admin.database().ref('Users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
app.get('/get', (req, res, next) => {
    getUsers().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    })
})
```

this is working for me.
Hope it can help

Comment: If you're adding return in the arrow function, does it work ?
`const ref = await firebaseApp.database().ref('users');
return ref.once('value').then(data => {
    return data.val();
})`

Comment: Is your `console.log()` in app.get return the item ? If not check in your functions and display the result.
Please update your post with some results of `console` in app.get and `getUsers()`.

Comment: That means that your return will wait until your query is done. So after that you should have something inside of your variable : `const variable = firebaseApp.database().ref('users').once('value');`
Then if you do `console.log(variable.val());` or just `console.log(variable);`, you should get an output. If not check your query.

Comment: I've created a projet and I've updated my post. The code is working.

Comment: My database has users collection with userdoc which has fields... But dont know what am doing wrong with database. So that am getting null in database().ref('users'). Thanks for ur code..

Comment: I can't really help you on realtime DB ^^. I'm using Firestore instead. Have a nice day. Please mark as resolved if this is what you was looking for :).

Comment: maybe your select wrong project. Run command "firebase use --add" to add right project. Then open your serviceAccountKey.json file to make sure it is your project. re-run "firebase serve", your functions url will like http://localhost:5000/{YOUR_PROJET_ID}/us-central1/app. Run http://localhost:5000/{YOUR_PROJET_ID}/us-central1/app/get to check result